# How can I show mutlitple Rows in Visiual Studio 2013 Website project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm using C# language and Visual Studio 2013. I'm trying to show multiple rows in my website but it's only showing the first result

I'm trying

```
String show = "Select Posts from userPosts where Username='John'";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(show, con);
String str = com.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
Response.Write(str);
```

This is only showing the first result with the user name `JOHN` but I want them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `ExecuteScalar` [Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored. ]

Try `ExecuteReader`.

```
String show = "Select Posts from userPosts where Username='John';
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(show, connection))
    {
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(i));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    }
```

BTW You can try light ORM like Dapper https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net. It really nicely remove these horrible `while` loop

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have used `ExecuteScalar()` Try it like this (the result is shown in a `DataGridView`):

```
String show = "Select Posts from userPosts where Username='John'";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(show,con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds,"tbl");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

If you don't want to show in `DataGridView` and just store in a variable use a `List<string>` like this:

```
List<string> Posts = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    Posts.Add(item[0].ToString());
}
```

Also you can use [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) as another option.

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteScalar()- It executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx.

Instead of ExecuteScalar use  ExecuteReader